# In Stargate: Atlantis episode Lifeline (S4E02), why doesn't the anti-replicator field affect Elizabeth Weir?

Tags: aliens, stargate, stargate-atlantis, nanotechnology

Her nanites ought to have been disabled by the field, why wasn't she affected?  Is there an in-universe explanation that I missed?

Answer (score 10):

They adapted the cloak to disable the replicator nanites.  The cloak only alters things on the external surface of the puddle jumper normally, it doesn't extend a field inside the jumper itself.  The field initially materialized around the ship and she stayed in the ship, so she wasn't exposed to it then.  When she left the ship, the replicators had adapted to the field.  So Weir's nanites could have also adapted to the field, as they were in communication with the replicators.

Comment: Plausible I suppose.  But it seems like a stretch.  Given the way the anti-replicator weapons work -- they use a certain frequency of em energy to disable the nanites bonding ability -- it shouldn't matter that it was the cloak generator they used to generate the field.  It ought to effect all nanites inside the field.  Also, I had the sense she stopped Oberoth before he entered the field.  But I suppose it isn't really made explicit either way.

Comment: The hallway in which Oberoth and Weir were "fighting" was one that the SG team was using for their heist. They ran past Weir and Oberoth on the way back to the ship. So that hall must have been inside the field perimeter. In addition, at that point the replicators had adapted to the field anyway, so Weir's nanites may have adapted too.

Comment: Thinking more about this, my initial answer didn't make sense.  We see replicators pierce the field for a little bit as they start adapting to it.  So being within the field must cause the nanites to become inert.  I've edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: The field only disables replicator cells that pass through it, she was always inside it so she was never disabled. When the field was created it started around the ship (didn't grow from the center of it) and extended downwards, killing replicators that would have been inside the field, but not wier inside the ship.

Comment: @Jonathan That's what I thought too, but we saw replicators start to get through the field, getting further each time they adapted. So either the field has a really thick boundary, or anything in the field is affected.

Comment: @Keen, they were able to get through the field more and more because the were adapting themselves through trial and error. Each time a replicator was kiled it sent back information that they used to adapt further the next time, until they were able to get through completely. The reason they were able to get through is because of what the replicators did, not to do with the shield. (The shield made the bonds between the cells unstable, they changed themselves to delay this, and each time a rep died it got delayed further until it never happened)

Comment: @Keen Your original, un-edited answer was correct, now it is not.  As said in Jonathan's comment, the field disrupted the replicators that passed through it - it didn't immediately shut them down.  The instability from the disruption was reduced with each iteration, lengthening the time before complete failure occured (hence appearing to "push through"), but the disruption itself was a one-time event as they passed through the thin field.

Answer (score 3):

The cloak field might not propagate through the hull of the ship, and the generation is likely an external grid.